# Deleting an item from a MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js.
I got this document:

```
   {
   users: [ '614e000c826b2308ec49508d', '614e0021826b2308ec49508e' ],
   _id: 61d5fe6af420232658ffe131,
   name: 'Standard',
   __v: 0
   }
```

Which I assigned to a variale `groupToEdit`

I'm trying to remove one of the elements in the `users` array with this line:

```
    await groupToEdit.updateOne(
      { _id: '61d5fe6af420232658ffe131' },
      { $pull: { 'users': '614e000c826b2308ec49508d' } }
    )
```

But nothing is removed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_id` should be `"_id"` in `updateOne()`.

Comment: Thanks but sill nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style:

```
await yourCollection.updateOne({
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('61d5fe6af420232658ffe131')}, {
  $pull: { 'users': '614e000c826b2308ec49508d' }
});
```

Your problem is that mongoDB store `_id` as `ObjectId` and you are passing it as a `string`. Type of the id you pass is important.

Comment: Thank you. One more correction to make it work was to invoke 'updateOne' on the collection and not on the document. Please edit that to your answer so I can mark it accepted.